# What does $TM$, $T^*M$ and $*$ mean?(Definition Check)

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, definition

I was reading Hamilton's Ricci Flow by Bennett Chow Peng Lu and Lei Ni.

However, I encountered some notation confusion:

1. What does $TM$ mean? Does $T$ stands for tensor or tangent, "M" for metric?
2. What's the difference between $TM$ and $T^*M$?
3. Also, there seemed to be a custom to use $*$ for either space or functions, i.e. $V^*$ or $\varphi_*$. What does $*$ indicate here? Does it indicate dual space or something else?

(The preview of the material is available on amazon. )

Image I:

[image]

Image II:

[image]

Comment: $TM$ is the tangent bundle of the manifold $M$.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thank you, so what does $*$ stands for?

Comment: $T^*M$ is the cotangent bundle; $\varphi_*$ usually will denote an induced map on tangent bundle, homology, fundamental group, or some other derived object.

Comment: On a vector space, a superscript $*$ usually indicates the dual.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this question?

Comment: The objects for which you are confused about typically take some time to understand, considering a lot of specific examples and working many exercises. If you find difficulty understanding this text, I recommend taking a step back and gaining more familiarity with these objects first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T_pM$ is the space of vectors tangent to $M$ at $p$, and $T_p^*M=(T_pM)^*$ is the corresponding dual space.

$TM$ is the  tangent bundle of manifold, $T^*M$ is the cotangent bundle of the manifold. 
$$ TM=\bigsqcup_{p\in M} T_pM$$
subject to the "gluing" conditions that $TM$ is "locally" of  the form $U\times \mathbb{R}^n$ for $U$ an open neighborhood of $M$. These objects are called smooth vector bundles and you can read more about them in a book like

$(1)$ Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*

$(2)$ Tu's *An Introduction to Manifolds*.